# Raspberry Pi 4 Thonny Opencv

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, syntax-error, raspberry-pi4, thonny

I cannot run my code that I wrote on python IDE 3.11  to the python Thoonny 3.9.
I downloaded the opency libraty:https://qengineering.eu/install-opencv-on-raspberry-pi.html.
I also used picamera2 library but fail.
How should I integrate my code to raspberry pi 4 python Thoonny 3.9?

Error:

```
[ WARN:0@0.393] global cap_gstreamer.cpp:2784 handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module v4l2src0 reported: Failed to allocate required memory.
[ WARN:0@0.394] global cap_gstreamer.cpp:1679 open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline
[ WARN:0@0.394] global cap_gstreamer.cpp:1164 isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
failed to grab frame
[ WARN:0@0.568] global loadsave.cpp:244 findDecoder imread_('analog_gauge_30.png'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 152, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 41, in take_measure
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

def avg_circles(circles, b):
    avg_x = 0
    avg_y = 0
    avg_r = 0
    for i in range(b):
        avg_x = avg_x + circles[0][i][0]
        avg_y = avg_y + circles[0][i][1]
        avg_r = avg_r + circles[0][i][2]
    avg_x = int(avg_x / (b))
    avg_y = int(avg_y / (b))
    avg_r = int(avg_r / (b))
    return avg_x, avg_y, avg_r

def dist_2_pts(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return np.sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2)

def take_measure(threshold_img, threshold_ln, minLineLength, maxLineGap, diff1LowerBound, diff1UpperBound, diff2LowerBound, diff2UpperBound):
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cv2.namedWindow("test")
    img_counter = 30
    while True:
        ret, frame = cam.read()
        if not ret:
            print("failed to grab frame")
            break
        cv2.imshow("test", frame)
        k = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if k % 256 == 27:
            print("Escape hit, closing...")
            break
        elif k % 256 == 32:
            img_name = "analog_gauge_{}.png".format(img_counter)
            cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
            print("{} written!".format(img_name))
            break
    img = cv2.imread("analog_gauge_30.png")
    height, width = img.shape[:2]
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20)
    if circles is not None:
        a, b, c = circles.shape
        x, y, r = avg_circles(circles, b)
        cv2.circle(img, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.circle(img, (x, y), 2, (0, 255, 0), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
        min_angle = 0
        max_angle = 360
        min_value = 0
        max_value = 16
        separation = 10
        interval = int(360 / separation)
        p1 = np.zeros((interval, 2))
        p2 = np.zeros((interval, 2))
        p_text = np.zeros((interval, 2))
        for i in range(0, interval):
            for j in range(0, 2):
                if (j % 2 == 0):
                    p1[i][j] = x + 0.9 * r * np.cos(separation * i * 3.14 / 180)
                else:
                    p1[i][j] = y + 0.9 * r * np.sin(separation * i * 3.14 / 180)
                    text_offset_x = 10
                    text_offset_y = 5
                    for i in range(0, interval):
                        for j in range(0, 2):
                            if (j % 2 == 0):
                                p2[i][j] = x + r * np.cos(separation * i * 3.14 / 180)
                                p_text[i][j] = x - text_offset_x + 1.2 * r * np.cos((separation) * (i + 9) * 3.14 / 180)
                            else:
                                p2[i][j] = y + r * np.sin(separation * i * 3.14 / 180)
                                p_text[i][j] = y + text_offset_y + 1.2 * r * np.sin((separation) * (i + 9) * 3.14 / 180)
        for i in range(0, interval):
            cv2.line(img, (int(p1[i][0]), int(p1[i][1])), (int(p2[i][0]), int(p2[i][1])), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.putText(img, '%s' % (int(i * separation)), (int(p_text[i][0]), int(p_text[i][1])), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.3, (255, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.putText(img, "Gauge OK!", (50, 75), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            gray3 = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            maxValue = 255
            th, dst2 = cv2.threshold(gray3, threshold_img, maxValue, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV);
            cv2.imshow('test3', dst2)
            dst2 = cv2.medianBlur(dst2, 5)
            dst2 = cv2.Canny(dst2, 50, 150)
            dst2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(dst2, (5, 5), 0)
            in_loop = 0
            lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image=dst2, rho=3, theta=np.pi / 180, threshold=threshold_ln, minLineLength=minLineLength, maxLineGap=maxLineGap)
            final_line_list = []
            for i in range(0, len(lines)):
                for x1, y1, x2, y2 in lines[i]:
                    diff1 = dist_2_pts(x, y, x1, y1)
                    diff2 = dist_2_pts(x, y, x2, y2)
                    if (diff1 > diff2):
                        temp = diff1
                        diff1 = diff2
                        diff2 = temp
                    if (((diff1 < diff1UpperBound * r) and (diff1 > diff1LowerBound * r) and (diff2 < diff2UpperBound * r)) and (diff2 > diff2LowerBound * r)):
                        line_length = dist_2_pts(x1, y1, x2, y2)
                        final_line_list.append([x1, y1, x2, y2])
                        in_loop = 1
            if (in_loop == 1):
                x1 = final_line_list[0][0]
                y1 = final_line_list[0][1]
                x2 = final_line_list[0][2]
                y2 = final_line_list[0][3]
                cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 255), 2)
                dist_pt_0 = dist_2_pts(x, y, x1, y1)
                dist_pt_1 = dist_2_pts(x, y, x2, y2)
                if (dist_pt_0 > dist_pt_1):
                    x_angle = x1 - x
                    y_angle = y - y1
                else:
                    x_angle = x2 - x
                    y_angle = y - y2
                res = np.arctan(np.divide(float(y_angle), float(x_angle)))
                res = np.rad2deg(res)
                if x_angle > 0 and y_angle > 0:
                    final_angle = 270 - res
                if x_angle < 0 and y_angle > 0:
                    final_angle = 90 - res
                if x_angle < 0 and y_angle < 0:
                    final_angle = 90 - res
                if x_angle > 0 and y_angle < 0:
                    final_angle = 270 - res
                    old_min = float(min_angle)
                    old_max = float(max_angle)
                    new_min = float(min_value)
                    new_max = float(max_value)
                    old_value = final_angle
                    old_range = (old_max - old_min)
                    new_range = (new_max - new_min)
                    new_value = ((((old_value - old_min) * new_range) / old_range) + new_min) - 1.4
                    cv2.putText(img, "Indicator OK!", (50, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
                    cv2.putText(img, str(new_value), (50, 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
                    print("Res:", res)
                    print("Final Angle: ", final_angle)
                    print("New value", new_value)
                else:
                    cv2.putText(img, "Can't find the indicator!", (50, 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            else:
                cv2.putText(img, "Can't see the gauge!", (50, 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            return img, img

while True:
    threshold_img = 120
    threshold_ln = 150
    minLineLength = 40
    maxLineGap = 8
    diff1LowerBound = 0.15
    diff1UpperBound = 0.25
    diff2LowerBound = 0.5
    diff2UpperBound = 1.0
    img, img2 = take_measure(threshold_img, threshold_ln, minLineLength, maxLineGap, diff1LowerBound, diff1UpperBound, diff2LowerBound, diff2UpperBound)
    cv2.imshow('Analog Gauge RESULT', img2)
    if ord('q') == cv2.waitKey(1):
        break
```

Comment: learn about "current working directory" and relative paths.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz what do you mean by relative path and the current working directory is picamera 2 right?